# Eclipse Freeze/Not Responding when searching for maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse on a windows computer and I am able to add 1 dependency from a global repository, but when I try to add another that I need my Eclipse just loads for a long time and eventually gives me the "Not Responding" message. I have tried changing preferences, I have made sure my system has enough memory on the hard drive, I have tried enabling full index and rebuilding indexes, and I have also tried running as maven clean within the workspace. I also opened my .log file and at the very bottom it gives me a message that says:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator 2 0 2022-02-01 15:27:10.371
!MESSAGE Can't find Navigator Content Descriptor with id: org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.EnhancedJavaRendering
```

I was wondering if this was the source of my issue, and if so how do I fix it?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Can you post your POM file?

Comment: I am using the newest version of eclipse I think, I don't know how I could add the POM file

Comment: Copy and paste the contents of the POM.

Comment: Please tell the exact version number of your Eclipse and of the m2e plugin since _newest_ is not a proper version number. Please also tell the preferences you have for Maven. Do you mean by _"enabling full index"_ the option _Download repository index updates on startup_? The warning in the log seems unrelated (please add the log starting with `!SESSION`).